# The name of God in ancient manuscripts

Tags: hebrew, aramaic, names-of-god

I came across [the following from an unofficial/unverified source](http://www.bibletopics.com/biblestudy/154.htm#3):

> Yahu An alternative spelling and pronunciation of Yahweh, found
>   (spelled YHW) on a circa 800 B.C.E. ostracon from Kuntillet Ajrud and
>   (spelled YHW and YHH) in the documents written by Aramaic-speaking
>   fifth-century B.C.E. Jews living in Elephantine in Egypt. The form
>   Yahu is also used in biblical theophoric names (names that include the
>   name of a god) like Yeho-natan (Jonathan; Judges 18:30) and Yesha-yahu
>   (Isaiah). Although most scholars take Yahu to be a short form of
>   Yahweh, it might also be an earlier form of the divine name.[3](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94)[2]
>   Blockquote

This strikes me as significant, because, His name is sometimes rendered Yah in the Hebrew text, [said by some to be pronounced, *yâhh/yaw*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94).

NKJV:

> Psalms 68: 4 Sing to God, sing praises to His name; Extol Him who rides on the clouds, By His name YAH, And rejoice before Him.
>
> Isaiah 12: 2  Behold, God is my salvation, I will trust and not be
>   afraid; ' For YAH, the LORD, is my strength and song; He also has
>   become my salvation.' "
>
> Isaiah 26: 4  Trust in the LORD forever, For in YAH, the LORD, is
>   everlasting strength.
>
> Isaiah 38: 11  I said, " I shall not see YAH, The LORD in the land of
>   the living; I shall observe man no more among the inhabitants of the
>   world.

Both YHWH and YAH are said to be His name.  Is it possible that neither YHWH nor Yah is a contraction nor expansion of the other, but that both the same only in a different language?

Can anyone confirm/verify that there are manuscripts that contain the divine name as Yahu YHH and elaborate on this for me? 
More specifically:
Is this how His name is rendered in all cases in these manuscripts or only in some passages? 
How does Exodus 3:15 read in these manuscripts?
Exactly how is His name rendered in the script of these documents?

NKJV:

> Exodus 3
>   14    And God said to Moses, "I AM WHO I AM." And He said, "Thus
>   you shall say to the children of Israel, 'I AM has sent me to you.' "
>   15 Moreover God said to Moses, "Thus you shall say to the children of
>   Israel: 'The LORD God of your fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of
>   Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you. This is My name
>   forever, and this is My memorial to all generations.' 16 Go and gather
>   the elders of Israel together, and say to them, 'The LORD God of your
>   fathers, the God of Abraham, of Isaac, and of Jacob, appeared to me,
>   saying, "I have surely visited you and seen what is done to you in
>   Egypt;

[2]: See Lienhard Delekat, “Yáho-Yahwáe und die alttestamentlichen Gottesnamenkorrekturen,” in Tradition und Glaube, ed. Gert Jeremias et al. (Göttingen: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht, 1971), pp. 23-75.

Comment: There's not a double ה. Rather the ה has a mappik in it, thus הּ, as in יָהּ. However, it doesn't mean the ה should be pronounced as הה. Rather, it means that the ה should be vocalized, whereas name without it, the ה is simply unvocalized.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mappiq

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.  Just out of curiosity, if you know off the top of your head, are there other words that end with a vocalized ה like that?  That is difficult to even do much less in the context of singing (where this mostly occurs).

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94

Comment: Another word (off top of my head) is גֹּבַהּ, meaning "height."

Comment: + See the related question: "[Does Song of Songs 8:6 contain a reference to YHWH?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12949/2215)": "...How is *-yah* best understood here?"

Comment: You might want to consider ancient Jewish Biblical commentators who found that when the Divine four-letter Name was used, God would be acting with his attribute of Mercy, and that when Elokim (for religious reasons I've changed the h to a k) is used, God is acting in a more judgmental capacity.  From that analysis there are very interesting insights that can be reached.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These **variations in the divine name** are not so much about different languages, but different phases of Hebrew. See the YHWH article by [Freedman, O'Connor & Ringgren](http://goo.gl/4y1IAi) in *[Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pcAkKMECPKIC)*, (Eerdmans, 1986), vol. 5, pp. 500-521.

The "contracted" forms are usually used in [theophoric names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophoric_name):

- at the beginning:

  - *yəhô-* as in יְהוֹאָחָז , Jehoahaz ([2 Kings 10:35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20kings%2010%3A35&version=NASB;WLC))
  - *yo-* as in יוֹנָתָן, Jonathan ([1 Samuel 13:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+samuel+13%3A16&version=NASB;WLC))
- at the end:

  - *-yahû* as in  אֲדֹנִיָּהוּ, Adonijah (*ʾădōniyyāhû*, [1 Kings 1:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+kings+1%3A8&version=NASB;WLC))
  - *-yāh* as in חִזְקִיָּה, Hezekiah (*ḥizqiyyāh*, [2 Kings 18:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+kings+18%3A13&version=NASB;WLC))

The short form *yah* also appears in certain **hymnic settings** (as noted by OP), with many scholars finding the oldest poem in which this occurs to be [Psalm 68:4, 18](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=abs%3Aeng-NASB&v1=PS68_4&w2=bible&t2=local%3Aheb_wlc&v2=PS68_3) (vv. 5 and 15 in Hebrew - see also [Rashi's comment](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16289#v=5&showrashi=true) on v. 5).

On the **[form יהּ](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/219/mode/1up) and its pronunciation**:<sup>1</sup> הּ (with the internal "dot", which here is a *mappiq*) means that it should **not** be understood to represent a vowel, thus יהּ = *yāh* [note final "h", where it has consonantal force: it is *not* quiescent], but not *yâ*.<sup>2</sup>

The *TDOT* article also points out (p. 504) that both *yhh* and *yhw* spellings are known from the [Aramaic papyri of Elephantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephantine_papyri) (*c.* 5th C. BCE). The "Elephantine Papyri" are *not* biblical manuscripts, however. This invaluable corpus from a [Jewish community in Egypt](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4149987) is comprised of personal letters and legal documents (for the most part, also one or two "literary" texts). For full details, see Bezalel Porten's [fundamental treatment](http://goo.gl/4D2SyL).

N.b., **Exodus 3:14** does not use the divine name; that only comes in Exodus 3:15, and it appears there in its normal four-letter ("tetragram") form. Perhaps it would be of interest to note that on those occasions when YHWH is identified as the divine name (יְהוָה שְׁמוֹ, *yhwh šəmô* = "YHWH is his name!", Exod. 15:3; Jer. 33:2; Amos 5:8; 9:6) it is always the full form of the Tetragram.

From other extra-biblical evidence, the "blessing" inscriptions from **[Kuntillet 'Ajrud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuntillet_Ajrud)** each use the full *yhwh* form of the divine name: "I bless you by YHWH of Samaria and his asherah" or the like.<sup>3</sup>

There has been much scholarly discussion, of course. By way of **further reading**, Tryggve **Mettinger**'s *[In Search of God: The Meaning and Message of the Everlasting Names](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lZL2A-JLMcQC)* (Fortress, 1988, 2005) has much of interest on this topic; it should be available in college or seminary libraries. See also e.g., Josef **Tropper**, "[Der Gottesname **Yahwa*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1585568)", *Vetus Testamentum*, 51/1 (2001): 81-106.

<sub>See also the related question: "[Is יהוה ever transliterated in the Septuagint?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/12951/2215)", where the Qumran evidence shows the older alphabetic form of writing Y-H-W-H.</sub>

---

*Notes*

1. For other names compounded with an element of the divine name, see also the entries that follow the יהּ entry in the listing of [Brown-Driver-Briggs](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/219/mode/1up) provided.
2. For an explanation of the use of *mappiq*, see Gesenius-Kautzsch-Cowley, *Hebrew Grammar*, [§14a, on Mappîq and Rāphè](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/14._Mapp%C3%AEq_and_R%C4%81ph%C3%A8#GHGpar-14-a).
3. For image and discussion, see Othmar Keel and Christoph Uehlinger, *[Gods, Goddesses, And Images of God](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NjYAWXO-jdAC)* (Fortress Press, 1998), [esp. p. 214](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NjYAWXO-jdAC&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q&f=false); see also David Noel Freedman, "[Yahweh of Samaria and His Asherah](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3210051)", *The Biblical Archaeologist* 50/4 (1987): 241-249.

Comment: The source of the author's information is Here is the source for the quote in the question:  3  See Lienhard Delekat, “Yáho-Yahwáe und die alttestamentlichen Gottesnamenkorrekturen,” in Tradition und Glaube, ed. Gert Jeremias et al. (Göttingen: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht, 1971), pp. 23-75.  Is this a credible source?

Comment: @Sarah - yes, Delekat's work is "credible". You can see some later uses of it [on Google Scholar](http://goo.gl/JlP8xb). | And have modified answer to clarify on Elephantine (plus one or two other tweaks).

Answer (score 8):

Great references @David, but after the exile there appears to be a linguistic aspect to the variations. We can begin by separating the historical phases—pre-exilic, exilic, and post-exilic periods.

Many have puzzled over all the variations of the name, because if derived from it they should somehow “resemble” the full name itself (and only one does this—the poetic form *Yāh* with stress lengthening). They all do not: beginning *yəhô*-, *yô*-, and at end -*yā́hû*, and -*yāh*.

Firstly, in the pre-exilic period both the full name YHWH and abbreviations are found, but to understand both Hebrew orthography, Neo-Assyrian transcriptions, and the religious contexts of Yahweh all help. YHWH (not *yāhû*) appears clearly (but syncretistically) at Kuntilet Ajrud (9th-8th century B.C.E.). The instances of “YHW” are where the final /h/ seems missing and Gogle restores it (Sandra Gogle, *A Grammar of Epigraphic Hebrew* [Atlanta: Scholars Press, 1998], 414–415). Mesha stele (9th century B.C.E), Arad, and Lachish (8th to 6th century) give clear use of YHWH.

Inscriptions attest to mostly two abbreviated forms of the name Yahweh—in northern Israel only -*yw*- at beginning and end of names (Samaria ostraca); in Judah mostly -*yhw*- also at beginning and end (but for a short time also -*yw-* in eighth century). See Ran Zadok, *The Pre-Hellenistic Israelite Anthroponymy and Prosopography* (Leuven: Uitgeverij Peeters, 1988), 184. Throughout the earlier to the later periods we always find the initial long *yhw*- consistently with /w/ visible, not defective (and hence not vocalic), and by the sixth century in Judah only the ubiquitous long -yhw- is found, indicating *yahw*. The short form then of *yw*-/-*yw* (also not defective) found mostly in northern Israel appears derived from it, but with dropping of /h/ (*yaw*). The /h/ made no difference in sound, only in an indication of the source—*Yahweh*. Also, Neo-Assyrian (Zadok, *Pre-Hellenistic*, 302) shows West Semitic consonantal /w/ and vocalic /ū/ both spelled exactly with vowel  (and <ú>) (ḫa-za-qi-ia-a-u LÚ ia-ú-da-a-a—*Hazaqyahw Yahudaya*). Also, it couldn’t represent /h/. Thus, the pre-exilic period attests to only YHWH in both secular and religious uses, with no mystery about use in Judah or “ineffability.”

The same cannot be said in exile. When one peruses the book of Daniel an interesting phenomenon can be discerned—the name Yahweh is never found in the Aramaic portions (Dan 2:18–20), only the terms *Elah* and *Elah of Heaven* (like in Ezra and Aramaic-speaking Elephantine Jews). In the Hebrew section of Daniel, however, the name Yahweh is found (Dan 9), which is not a Hellenistic *pesher* practice. Yet, in Aramaic we never find a *Yāhū*.

Transcriptions of "Jehoiachin" and "Judah" from Weidner Texts
[image: Neo-Babylonian Transcriptions from Weidner Texts]
It is at the beginning of the exile we first certainly find the spelling *yāhū* in the famous Neo-Babylonian cuneiform ration tablets that mention King Jehoiachin. The key is in the strange spelling ***ia-ku-ú***-ki-nu for the king and the name Judah also strangely found as *ia-ku-du*, with /h/ represented by < k >. This is not the usual way to transcribe either. We saw in Neo-Assyrian above how *Hazakyahw* and *Yahûdāh* were transcribed (without /h/ represented). But now, in both these the < k > ensures our only vocalization of the /h/ in the Hebrew name is in a pronunciation /hu/, transforming our abbreviated name *yhw* (now /w/ = /ū/—as a *mater lexionis*). Nevertheless, in Neo-Babylonian two differences that help us confirm the correct form of the king’s name are that the Babylonian scribes now use the grapheme <ḫ> to indicate the true aspirated /h/ sound (which didn’t happen in Neo-Assyrian), and they use < ma > to indicate consonantal /w/ (again a new thing). These ensure the vocalizations in the table above, as in *Yāhûd* (< Yahûdāh) and *šalamyahw* above. *But, by 583 B.C.E. we do find the regular spelling ia(?)-a-ḫu-* (/h/ represented by /ḫ/) *for the first time applied to personal names as well, continuing the practice of yahu*- (like in ***ia-ku-ú***-ki-nu). See Ran Zadok, *The Earliest Diaspora: Israelites and Judeans in Pre-Hellenistic Mesopotamia* (Tel Aviv, 2002), 28. This is the ubiquitous form then on. But, *yāhū* is still only found in personal names not yet independently.

One may ask, if Yahweh led to -*yahw*- (and reflected by ia-ʾ-ú-) where then did *yāhū-* in names originate? These cuneiform texts give the answer, where we see the strange spelling of < k > for /hu/ in **ia-ku-ú**-ki-nu and in *ia-ku-du* for *Yāhûd*, shortened form of *Yahûdāh*, seen in Ezra 5:1 (the /a/ typically being left off in Hellenistic period). It was inspired by the spelling of the geographic name spelled in cuneiform sometimes like the abbreviated name as in Text A, [KU]R *ia-ú-du*, and the king’s name spelled ia-ʾ-ú-kīnu(DU). **In other words -*yāhû*- *in names came from* *Yāhûd*.** The goal was to protect the form of Yahweh from being accidentally spoken in personal names in foreign tongues (as in a possible *ia-a-ú-ia-ki-nu* = *yahwiakin*).

This brings us to the post-Exilic period where the Elephantine Jews did use *Yāhû* as the name of the deity (but we never find YHWH), because this *yāhû* in names was assumed to be the Judean deity in Babylonia. But most Judeans, knowing the origin, opted for the other shortened abbreviation of Yahweh, not *yahw*, but stressed final *Yāh* (and only final) (a poetic abbreviation of Yahweh–Exo 15:2), which stressed would then sound exactly like *yahw* (/aw/ in **au**to not in c**ow**). This is why on a personal name spelled in a cuneiform document as pi-il-**ia-a-ma** there was the same name spelled in Aramaic on the endorsement on the outside *plyh*, which shows *ia-a-ma* = *yh*. See Matthew Stolper, “A Note on Yahwistic Personal Names in the Murašû Texts,” *Bulletin of the American Schools of Oriental Research* 222 (1976): 27. But, *ia-a-ma* actually indicates *yahw* but only in Hebrew.

Since the Bible was primarily written in Hebrew the name YHWH is intact and we never find independent YHW (*yāhû*). But our difficulty lies in personal names, where two things happened: a pronunciation shift occurred but later at the end of the fourth century, and a “leveling” occurred of the consonantal distribution, with a similar intent as in the exilic period, protection of the “ineffable” name.

Comment: Nice answer.  FYI, it is encouraged to post new answers to old questions in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) to help make sure they don't get lost.  As such, I have posted this there...  If you have the time, there are numerous opportunities to contribute knowledge in chat conversations as well, and I think it would be great to hear your voice there.

Comment: Thank you Thaddeus! Excellent tip. I didn't realize how colossal this site really is, and there are many areas I haven't ventured into quite yet! I'll be sure to check it out!