# Which words are used for God in the oldest manuscripts of the New Testament?

Tags: greek, new-testament, names-of-god

Basically my question is the NT counterpart of this question: [The name of God in ancient manuscripts](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/the-name-of-god-in-ancient-manuscripts)

**My question:**
Which words are used for God in the oldest manuscripts of the New Testament?

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote? It is good practice on SE to state your reasons. How can I improve this question?

Comment: @Soldarnal: I am writing to you as an experienced moderator of this site: Do you have any idea why this question is downvoted? Is it not a good fit? How can I improve it? Thank you

Comment: I think it's probably being downvoted because it isn't a good fit for the site, not being about the anaylsis of biblical texts as defined in the help centre, which is why a number of users have voted to Close your question. Another reason might be that it demonstrates a lack of basic research, because there is only one real word for God in Greek and it's used throughout all NT manuscripts both early and late.

Comment: I think the DVs are probably because there is little to say about the Greek *theos*, and lots to say about the variety of linguistic forms of referring to the deity in classical Hebrew. A bit of research *might* have uncovered this -- but perhaps not, in which case, now you know! In spite of the similarity of titles betwen the two Q&As, they are quite different: there is a "real" question in the Hebrew sphere; that's not the case for Koine Greek. FWIW, IMO, YMMV, etc.

Comment: Nominated for re-opening as this question does arise from the breadth of NT biblical texts, and is relevant for users new to the topic who may be searching around this issue. Despite the answer's naturally low depth relative to its "OT Counterpart", this Question should be considered equally on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oldest manuscripts of the New Testament are all in **Greek**. Unlike Hebrew, Greek doesn't have very many terms for God.

- The Greek word for 'God' is [**θεός (Theos)**](http://biblehub.com/greek/2316.htm), which is used consistently throughout the New Testament.
- The common Jewish reference 'Lord', frequently a substitute for God's personal name [**יהוה (YHWH)**](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/3068.htm), is naturally rendered in Greek as [**κύριος (kurios)**](http://biblehub.com/greek/2962.htm), also meaning 'lord'.

These two terms are the most common words used for God throughout the New Testament, as they are also prominent in the [**LXX (Septuagint)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) translation of the Old Testament.

---

Jesus commonly uses [**πατήρ (pater)**](http://biblehub.com/greek/3962.htm) in reference to God as 'father', but also uses [**Ἀββᾶ (Abba)**](http://biblehub.com/greek/5.htm), which is a more intimate term common in Hebrew and Aramaic.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What is 'Lord' in Hebrew?

Comment: @vonjd, *'adon* is "lord" in Hebrew. Referring to God, it is often in the OT as *'adonai*, "my lord," the English long i sound at the end shows possession or in this case that this is the lord the speaker serves.